# How do we know that $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$ is greater or equal to $2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For one problem, we were supposed to know that:

$$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\geq 2.$$

How do you deduce this instantly when looking at the expression above?

Comment: Let $x^2=e^t$; then $x^2+1/x^2 = 2 \cosh t$.

Comment: Alternatively, let $x^2=y$; then $x^2+1/x^2$ is $y+1/y$ which it is easy to see is convex on $(0,\infty)$. Since it has slope 0 at $y=1$, its value there must be the minimum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality: $(A+B)/2\ge \sqrt{AB}$
for $A\ge 0, B\ge 0$. Take $A=x^2$ and $B=1/x^2$.

Answer (score 24):

Since you tagged this with precalculus, we'll try the following.  Start with the inequality $(x^2 - 1)^2 \geq 0$.  Then,
\begin{align*}
 (x^2 - 1)^2 \geq 0 && \implies && x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 &\geq 0 \\
 && \implies && x^4 + 1 &\geq 2x^2 \\
 && \implies && \frac{x^4 + 1}{x^2} & \geq 2 & \text{for } x \neq 0 \\
 && \implies && x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} & \geq 2.
\end{align*}
This was the inequality we wanted, except we have to be sure to exclude the case $x = 0$.

Answer (score 19):

If $x\neq 0$ then $$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\ge0\iff x^2-2+\frac{1}{x^2}\ge 0 \iff x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\ge 2$$

Answer (score 13):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: Nice.  I'm always a sucker for wordless proofs.

Comment: Thanks for [this](http://trigonography.com/2015/10/01/a-reciprocal-sum-inequality/) amazing site.

Comment: @Silent: Glad to be of service!  (Knowing people are actually visiting makes me want to update it more often. :)

Answer (score 9):

$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{x^4 + 1}{x^2}$

$     = \frac{x^4 - 2x^2 + 1}{x^2} + 2$

$     = \frac{(x^2 - 1)^2}{x^2} + 2$

$     \geq 0 + 2 = 2$

Comment: This was the line of argument that occurred to me, too.  But you need to use $\geq$ in the last line, not $>$.

Comment: @BrianTung you're right of course - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Its not instantly but once you know it and have seen it a couple of times it becomes common sense. This is a consequence of Am-Gm inequality :**a+b/2 ≥√(ab)** substitute a=x² and b=(1/x)².

Answer (score 2):

You said imediately.  So this argument is worse than the others but it was the first thing I thought of.

this is equivalent to showing if $w \ge 1$ then $w + 1/w \ge 2$ which is equivalent to showing $w-1 \le 1 - 1/w $.

And $1 - 1/w = (w -1)/w \le w-1$