# How can it be proven that $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geq2$, with $x$ and $y$ positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

So I realized that I have to prove it with the fact that $(x-y)^2+2xy=x^2+y^2$

So $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}+2=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}-2$

Due to the fact that  $(x+y)^2$ is a square, it will be positive

$x>0$ and $y>0$ so $xy>0$

So $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}>0$

So $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}>2$

But the problem is that I have proven that $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}>2$, but in the case of $x=y$, it is equal, so it has to be $\geq$...

Could someone help?

Comment: This has got to be one of the most frequently asked inequalities. The closest match I found in 30 seconds is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1460256/11619). Surely there is an exact dup...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But in this case, the OP needs help with his solution which is broken, so I think that is enough to not make it a dupe.

Comment: @wythagoras: Point taken. I have a vague recollection that it has been touched in a meta discussion, whether the question being of the solution verification type protects it from the dupe hammer. Couldn't find an exact match right away, so leaving the dupe hunt for now. Starring this for the eventuality that I need material for a future meta discussion.

Comment: I think the error is that you've replaced $(x+y)$ in your original argument where you used $(x-y)$, if you use $(x-y)$ you have the possibility $\frac{(x-y)^2}{xy} = 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With AM-GM $$\frac { x }{ y } +\frac { y }{ x } \geq 2\sqrt { \frac { x }{ y } \frac { y }{ x }  } = 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = x/y$, then this is equivalent to proving $a + 1/a \geq 2$. $a$ is positive so multiply both sides by $a$ we get

$$a^2 - 2a + 1 = (a - 1)^2 \geq 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a few mistakes here.

First, actually $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$, what you need is $(x-y)^2+2xy=x^2+y^2$. Now, you get $xy>0$ but $(x-y)^2 \geq 0$, so $\frac{(x-y)^2}{xy} \geq 0$, and this gives you $$\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{xy} \geq 0$$

which gives $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \geq 2$, which is the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left( \frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ \sqrt { y }  } -\frac { \sqrt { y }  }{ \sqrt { x }  }  \right) ^{ 2 }\ge 0$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{  { x }  }{ { y }  }+\frac {  { y }  }{ { x }  } \ge 2$$